# Dashboards and Dynamic Dashboards using LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

Can we create Dashboards/Dynamic Dashboards using Lightning Web Components. If so is there any documentation provided?

Thanks,
Venkat

Answer (score 1):

Below video explains how to build an external dashboard with LWC.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/live/videos/a2r3k000001WFJ2/codelive:-building-an-external-dashboard-with-lwc/